# Bayes' theorem problem for class 12 mathematics

Tags: probability

> A letter is known to come either from TATANAGAR or CALCUTTA. One the envelope just two consecutive letters TA are visible. What is the probability that the letter comes from CALCUTTA, and what is the probability that it comes from TATANAGAR?

Comment: Use tree diagrams for these problems

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both locations are equally likely, and that each pair of letters is equally likely to be visible, we can use [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) to solve this problem. If the letter comes from Calcutta, there are seven possible letter combinations, one of them which is $TA$. If the letter comes from Tatanagar, there are eight possible combinations, two of them which are $TA$. Let $C$ and $T$ denote the events that the letter comes from Calcutta en Tatanagar, respectively. We then find:

$$P(C) = \frac{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{7}}{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{8}} = \frac{\frac{1}{14}}{\frac{1}{14} + \frac{1}{8}} = \frac{4}{4 + 7} = \frac{4}{11} \approx 0.364$$

$$P(T) = 1 - P(C) = \frac{7}{11} \approx 0.636$$

Comment: To me, the $letters$ cannot be in any order but the $names$ and the [apparently] torn envelope reveals part of one name or the other. I don't see how anything more complicated than first impressions are needed but you probably see something I did not in the question.

Comment: @ jvdhooft The reasoning for your answer is gibberish to me. What does the number of letters in the name have to do with probability? The only thing that seems to matter is the number of times the "TA" occurs in the name. Also, the calculation would be more believable if you could show that P(T) comes out the same without the shortcut of subtracting it from P(C).

Comment: @poetasis I am happy to elaborate. To make things more clear, imagine the cities A and BBBBBBBA. You find an envelope, and because it is burnt, you can only make out one letter: A. How did we get this outcome? Well, either the letter came from A, in which case we are sure to find the letter A, or the letter come from BBBBBBBA, in which case we have a probability of $\frac{1}{8}$ of finding A (assuming that all letters are equally likely to be found). Applying Bayes' theorem, we find $P(A|'A')=\frac{P(A,'A')}{P('A')}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{8}}=\frac{8}{9}$.

Comment: The above indicates a probability of $\frac{9}{16}$ to find the character 'A'. Indeed, we can also find the character 'B', with a probability of $\frac{1}{2}\frac{7}{8}=\frac{7}{16}$. If we find this character, then of course it immediately follows that it came from BBBBBBBA, as $P(A,'B')=0$.

Comment: @ jvdhooft The question is: "What are the chances of coming from T or C?" We need not consider any of the other letters in the names because we can $see$ TA which occurs twice in T and once in C. If we were wondering the odds of TA coming up in either without $seeing$ TA, your analysis would be correct but we $do$ see TA so it's just a matter of deciding which name it came from. There are two chances in T and one chance in C so I submit that the odds are as I suggested in my answer. It is the same problem as having the letters came from towns TA or TATA.

Comment: @poetasis Imagine two bins with balls, one containing one white ball and one containg seven red balls and one white ball. I randomly pick a bin and draw a white ball. What is the probability that I drew it from the first bin?

Comment: @ jvdhooft Given your question as stated, the odds are even that it came from either bin. If you had not $seen$ the white ball and we were wondering what are the odds, the answer would be more involved but we $do$ see the ball.

Comment: @poetasis The white ball in the first bin is 8 times as likely to be picked, and the chances of having drawn from the first bin is thus $\frac{8}{9}$. Imagine the same setup, but this time consider the first bin to hold 8 white balls. Now, regardless of which bin you choose, each of the 16 balls has the same probability of being drawn: $\frac{1}{16}$. You happen to draw a white ball - one of the 9 available. Do you see why the probability of having drawn this ball from the first bin equals $\frac{8}{9}$? Now replace the 8 white balls with a single ball - the probabily remains the same!

Comment: @ jvdhooft There is a difference between being likely to be picked and having been picked already. Having a white ball already picked, you may ask "Which did it likely come from?" and the answer is that the odds are equal. Likewise, if there were two white balls in with the seven reds, the chances would be $\frac{2}{3}$ that it came from the bin with the red balls–assuming we know that there are two whites with the red balls.

Comment: In the case of 8 white balls in one bin, I agree that the probability is $\frac{8}{9}$ that it was drawn from that bin instead of the one with 1 white and 7 red. Using a single white in the first bin changes the odds back to 1/2.

Comment: @poetatis We're one step closer to agreeing. Note that it does not matter how many white balls are in the white bag: if you choose the bag, the outcome will always be white. Therefore, the probability of drawing the single white ball equals $\frac{1}{2}$, the probability of having chosen the corresponding bag. If we chose the other bag, we only have a probability of $\frac{1}{8}$ of selecting the white ball, making this event much rarer. Therefore, observing a white ball gives a stronger indication of the first bag than the second: 8 times out of 9, the ball will be drawn from the first bag.

Comment: @poetatis You could try a small field experiment to test this hypothesis. Put two dice of different color in a bag: if the first color comes up, you roll the die regularly, if the second die comes up, you assume it rolls a one (this corresponds to a similar scenario as above). Shake them up and randomly draw one of the dice, and write down the result. Do this 30 times, and you will see that the number one corresponding to the first die will show up approximately six times as much as the number one on the second die.

Comment: This will be my last comment. Your analysis is correct if the question is about what are the chances you $will$ $see$ a TA from C or T but the question is posed as you $do$ $see$ a TA... and that changes the odds the way observing a quantum phenomenon collapses the superposition of something to one reality or another.

Comment: @poetasis Well, it was good to have the debate at least. Maybe one day you'll reflect on this, and get back to this post. In that case, please feel free to give me a shout. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? Since there are three occurrences of TA between the two letters, it seems to me that the chances are 1:3 for CALCUTTA and 2:3 for TATANAGAR. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

E1:  Letter (TA) came from Tatanagar

E2 :  Letter (TA) came from Calcutta

E : Event that 2 consecutive times the letter (TA) is visible.

P(E1) = P(E2) = 1/2

TATANAGAR can be broken down to : TA,AT,TA,AN,NA,AG,GA,AR = 8 pairs pairs in which two pairs contain the letter TA .
Therefore,
$P(\frac{\text{Number of times TA is present}}{\text{letter came from Tatanagar}}) = P(\frac{E}{_{E1}}) = \frac{2}{8}$

CALCUTTA can be broken down to : CA,AL,LC,CU,UT,TT,TA = 7 pairs in which ONE pair contains the letter TA .

$P(\frac{\text{Number of times TA is present}}{\text{letter came from Calcutta}}) = P(\frac{E}{_{E2}}) = \frac{1}{7}$
Then the Probability that the letter TA came from Calcutta when Just 2 consecutive letter(TA) are visible is given  = $P(\frac{E2}{E}) = \frac{P(E2) * P(\frac{E}{E2})}{{P(E2) * P(\frac{E}{E2}) + P(E1) * P(\frac{E}{E1})}} = \frac{\frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{7}}{\frac{1}{2} * [ \frac{1}{7} + \frac{2}{8}]} $